# How to keep ScrollView+LazyVStack scroll position when adding new items

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following view:

```swift
struct NCMediaScrollView: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: NCMediaScrollView, rhs: NCMediaScrollView) -> Bool {
        return lhs.metadatas == rhs.metadatas
    }

    @Binding var metadatas: [tableMetadata]
    @Binding var isInSelectMode: Bool
    @Binding var selectedMetadatas: [tableMetadata]
    @Binding var columnCountStages: [Int]
    @Binding var columnCountStagesIndex: Int
    @Binding var title: String
    @State private var dataID: String?

    let queuer: Queuer

    let onCellSelected: (ScaledThumbnail, Bool) -> Void
    let onCellContextMenuItemSelected: (ScaledThumbnail, ContextMenuSelection) -> Void
    let onRefresh: () async -> Void

    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()

        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                ForEach(metadatas.chunked(into: columnCountStages[columnCountStagesIndex]), id: \.self) { rowMetadatas in
                    NCMediaRow(metadatas: rowMetadatas, isInSelectMode: $isInSelectMode, queuer: queuer) { tappedThumbnail, isSelected in
                        onCellSelected(tappedThumbnail, isSelected)
                    } onCellContextMenuItemSelected: { thumbnail, selection in
                        onCellContextMenuItemSelected(thumbnail, selection)
                    }
                    .equatable()
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 70)
            .padding(.bottom, 40)
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
        .refreshable {
            await onRefresh()
        }

        .scrollPosition(id: $dataID, anchor: .bottom)
    }
}
```

Somewhere in the parent view's View Model I call:

```swift
self.metadatas.insert(contentsOf: updateMetadatas.metadatasUpdate, at: 0)
```

...to add new items to this array. This would then update the `@Binding` of metadatas in the above view.

The problem is that the content offset of the whole scroll view changes to add those views, and in turn the scroll view pushes up instead of remaining at the same position as before.

Since (I assume) the `LazyVStack` only lazily loads views when you scroll downwards, any views that are added on the top would be rendered the moment they are added. This is only an assumption of mine, and the problem may be something else.

---

What I tried to fix this:

1. Using iOS17 `scrollTargetLayout` + `scrollPosition`.

The documentation reads:

[image]

This is a bit vague and confusing, but I had assumed that it would try to keep the targeted view on the screen when a change occurs in the `ScrollView`. Sadly it didn't seem to do anything.

2. Capturing the scroll view `contentOffset` and setting it again when the array changes, but as I mentioned before, the contentOffset grows when new items are added, so this doesn't fix anything.

Using a `List` is not possible, since it's a very limiting View and causes a lot of functionality problems for this custom view.

Is there any way I can do this?